# Declare an array of objects using a for loop c++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, syntax, declaration

Okay. So I have declared an array of objects, and I have manually defined them using this code:

```
Object* objects[] =
{
    new Object(/*constructor parameters*/),
    new Object(/*constructor parameters*/)
};
```

Is there anyway to use some kind of a loop (preferably a for loop) to declare these? Something like:

```
Object* objects[] =
{
    for(int i=0; i<20; /*number of objects*/ i++)
    {
        new Object(/*constructor parameters*/);
    }
};
```

But with proper syntax?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I strongly suggest using a standard library container instead of arrays and pointers:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Object> objects;

// ...

void inside_some_function()
{
    objects.reserve(20);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        objects.push_back(Object( /* constructor parameters */ ));
    }
}
```

This provides exception-safety and less stress on the heap.

Comment: I tried that and it gives me some kind of error on the objects.reserve(20); line. It says it expects a constructor, destructor, or type conversion before the '.' token.

Comment: @Keelx: You cannot write statements in global scope, only within a function. You should put the `reserve` part right before the loop, see my edit.

Comment: Cool. Now what is the syntax to make them all pointers to Objects rather than actual objects?

Comment: Yes. And control of lifetime, etc. But I found out anyway. Thanks for Your help!

Answer (score 7):

```
Object* objects[20];

for(int i=0; i<20; /*number of objects*/ i++)
{
    objects[i] = new Object(/*constructor parameters*/);
}
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to it - +1. The only thing to watch for is calling "new" on a non-pointer type.

Comment: I've tried this method and It doesn't work. It gives me some unqualified-id error on the for loop.

Comment: @Keelx: Can you edit your question to include the exact code you used along with the error message you received?

Answer (score 2):

Points in C++ can be used as arrays. Try something like this:

```
// Example
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Object
{
public:
    Object(){}
    Object(int t) : w00t(t){}
    void print(){ cout<< w00t << endl; }
private:
    int w00t;
};

int main()
{
    Object * objects = new Object[20];
    for(int i=0;i<20;++i)
        objects[i] = Object(i);

    objects[5].print();
    objects[7].print();

    delete [] objects;
    return 0;
}
```

Regards,
Dennis M.

Comment: But... How will I declare the constructor if you have put the amount of objects in place of the constructor? How does that work?

Comment: You can declare/implement multiple constructors. My example has 2. One default constructor (the way the array was made) and another to simply hold the input value of a created object (if one is supplied).