# How to make multiple instances of a class in C++

Tags: c++, class, object

How do you create multiple class instances without individually typing in their names?

```
int main(){
    myClass myInstance_1;
    myClass myInstance_2;
    myClass myInstance_3;
    ...
    myClass myInstace_10;
}
```

Comment: Take `myClass myInstance[i];` **out** of the loop body, declaring it above the for-loop as `myClass myInstance[10];` If you're looking for a way to pass distinct values to the construction of an array for each member, you're not going to easily do it like this (and in fact may be the *real* problem you're trying to solve).

Comment: Do you compile with full warnings? Use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and an option to select the newest C++ standard wouldn't be amiss either. The compiler should then complain loudly over your code.

Comment: IMO and with all the respect: You really need to read a good C++ book.

Comment: A more complete answer is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8012152/9220905).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How do you create multiple class instances without individually typing in their names?**

The answer is you make an ***array***, but not the way you tried it.

**Like this:**

```
int main()
{
    MyClass myInstance[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        myInstance[i].myClassFunction();
    }
}
```

**TIP:** Don't use arrays, use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

(see answer from @Jarod42)

Answer (score 7):

You may do the following:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<myClass> myInstances;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        myInstances.emplace_back(i);
    }
    myInstances[5].myClassFunction();
}
```

Comment: If you insist on a std-container, best use the proper fit: `std::array`. Anyway, a raw array works too.

Comment: + I think it highly likely this is what is really the OP's goal: a different value for each *construction* of the element sequence.

Comment: Your code will not compile unless integer `i` can be casted to myClass.  I don't know who up-voted your answer.

Comment: @icando: See the question, the default ctor is `myClass(int i=0)` (Omitting `explicit`, which is a really bad idea).

Comment: @icando: [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/f82nhT). The single parameter constructor provides the very "unless" case you seem to think is missing. And "who up-voted" is in the very comment preceding yours.

Comment: @icando maybe read about emplace_back before you go saying it doesn't work: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1: Use an array of integers as an initializer, the constructor is used to convert the integer to myClass.

```
class myClass
{
public:
    //constructor
    myClass( int num) {m_number = num;};

    void myClassFunction(){cout<< "I am " << m_number << endl;}
private:

    int m_number;
};

int main(){
    myClass myInstance[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    for ( int i=0; i< 10; i++) myInstance[i].myClassFunction();
}
```

Solution 2: Use a static counter to set m_number, so no need to use a non-default constructor.

```
class myClass
{
public:
    //constructor
    myClass(){m_number=counter++;};

    void myClassFunction(){cout<< "I am " << m_number << endl;}
private:

    int m_number;
    static int counter;
};
int myClass::counter = 0;

int main(){
    myClass myInstance[10];
    for ( int i=0; i< 10; i++) myInstance[i].myClassFunction();
}
```

Solution 3: Set the m_number after the constructor call, so the default constructor is enough.

```
class myClass
{
public:
    //constructor
    void setNum(int num){m_number=num;};

    void myClassFunction(){cout<< "I am " << m_number << endl;}
private:

    int m_number;
};

int main(){
    myClass myInstance[10];
    for ( int i=0; i< 10; i++) myInstance[i].setNum(i);
    for ( int i=0; i< 10; i++) myInstance[i].myClassFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Jarod42's code:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<myClass> myInstances;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        myInstances.push_back(myClass(i));
    }
    myInstances[5].myClassFunction();
}
```

I think these should work.

Answer (score -2):

Use array:

```
myClass myInstance[10];
```

This will create an array with 10 instances but each instance will have its m_number set to 0.

Another approach:

```
myClass *myInstance = new myClass[10];

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
myInstance[i] = new myClass(i);
}
```

Here each instance will have different m_number values

---

Edit for the sake of fixing the problem with above code. Better solutions have already been proposed.

```
myClass *myInstance[10];

// Allocate
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
myInstance[i] = new myClass(i);
}

// At the end free
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
delete myInstance[i];
}
```

Comment: Avoid raw owning pointer, use `std::vector` instead. (and you miss one pointer BTW).

Comment: @Jarod42: Instead of raw owning pointers, the proper alternative is smart-pointers, right? Though any dynamic allocation is no good in this case.

Comment: You are allocating 2 times but not deleting?